# Getting a NullpointerException on my code

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am getting a Nullpointer on this code:

```
public void InsertImportantMsg (string msg, DateTime toDay, int visible)
    {

            connection.Open ();
            string query = "UPDATE IMPORTANTMESSAGE SET MESSAGES=':msg', DATETIME=':toDay', " +
                "LABELVISIBILITY=':visible'";
            connection.CreateCommand ();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Parameters.Add (":msg", msg);
            cmd.Parameters.Add (":toDay", toDay);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":visible", visible);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();

    }
```

Specifically at this line:

```
cmd.CommandText = query;
```

I am passing the parameters right. Is there something wrong with my update statement, that I don't realize?

(I know the code should be in try catch, but it's on purpose for now, so don't look at that)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: are you missing: cmd = connection.CreateCommand(); line above?

Comment: Are you *really* getting a `NullpointerException`? or are you getting a `NullReferenceException` ?

Comment: A quick use of debug mode would show which object is null and likely why.

Comment: dirk I know what a nullreference means, I just couldn't find it.

aurimas-neverauskas thanks, that was it. Seemed so simple, but I was unable to locate it after looking at it for a long time. I don't know how I ended up deleting that

Answer (score 1):

The immediate reason of the exception is that you *haven't assigned* `cmd` value.
The implementtation could be like that

```
public void InsertImportantMsg (string msg, DateTime toDay, int visible) {
  connection.Open();

  // Put IDisposable into using...
  using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    // Format query to be readble
    cmd.CommandText = 
      @"UPDATE IMPORTANTMESSAGE
           SET MESSAGES = :msg, -- <- you don't need apostrophes here...
               DATETIME = :toDay,
               LABELVISIBILITY = :visible";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(":msg", msg);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":toDay", toDay);

    //TODO: Check this - Oracle doesn't support boolean is SQL 
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":visible", visible);  

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know Oracle doesn't support boolean (unfortunately), but notice that visible is not a boolean value, but rather an int :D